# Optimization: max to softmax for convexity?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

Assume we have the following optimization problem: for a family of $m$ vectors $\{x_i\}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, a family of $l$ vectors $\{c_i\}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $l\ll m$  and for a family of $l$ variables $\{ a_i\} \in \mathbb{R}$ consider
\begin{align}
\arg \max_{i \in \{1,...,l\}} \quad -a_i(x-c_i)^T(x-c_i) \qquad(1)
\end{align}
or equivalently
\begin{align}
\arg \min_{i\in\{1,..l\}} \quad a_i(x-c_i)^T(x-c_i) \,\,\,\,\,\,\qquad(2)
\end{align}
and assume for the moment that all $a_i=1$. This can interpreted as: *pick the $i$ which minimizes the distance of the vector* $x$ *from the known vector* $c_i$. This is easy enough.

If we view the above as a Gaussian mixture, then one can set the vectors $a_i$ to belong to the interval $[0,1]$ with $$a_1+\ldots+a_l=1.$$

**The question** I have is how to recast (1) or (2) as a **constrained optimization problem** properly. One idea I read about online is that one can consider **softmax** as a smooth approximation to max. For a vector $y = \{y_1,...,y_l\}$,
$$
{\rm softmax(y)} = \log \exp(\sum_{i=1}^l y_i)
$$
Setting $-a_i(x-c_i)^T(x-c_i) \equiv y_i$, **does**
\begin{align}
    {\rm softmax}(y) &= \log \exp (y_1)+\log \exp(y_2)+\ldots + \log \exp(y_l) \\
                     &= \log\exp[-a_1(x-c_1)^T(x-c_1)+\ldots + log\exp[-a_l(x-c_i)^T(x-c_l)]
\end{align}
**correspond to a smooth version of** (1)? And if so, can it be used to solve the optimization problem with the constraints $\sum_{i=1}^la_l=1$ and **how**? **How would I solve this problem** (in principle)**?** If not, where is the fallacy in my question?